# creating a module in order to print nested functions in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have such type:

```
type lT = LV of name
        | LC of name
        | LA of lT * lT
        | LAb of name  * lT
```

I want to implement a function called let's say `s` in a way that, it is gonna behave in the following way:

```
let println x = printf "%s\n" (s x)
s (`App(`App(`App(`Bs, `K), `K), `K))  ==>  "B* K K K”
```

For this reason, I have implemented the following module:

```
module type L2C = 
sig
  val c1 : lT -> ([> `T | `L | `J
                        | `A of 'b * 'b | `V of name | `C of name] as 'b)

  val c2 : lT -> ([> `T | `L | `J | `C | `D
                        | `A of 'b * 'b | `V of name | `C of name] as 'b)

  val c3 : lT -> ([> `T | `L | `J | `C | `D | `Sp | `Bp | `Bs | `Cp
                        | `A of 'b * 'b | `V of name | `C of name] as 'b)

  val e : ([< `T | `L | `J | `C | `D | `Sp | `Bp | `Bs | `Cp
                        | `A of 'b * 'b | `V of name | `C of name] as 'b) ->
             ([ `T | `L | `J | `C | `D | `Sp | `Bp | `Bs | `Cp
                        | `A of 'b * 'b | `V of name | `C of name] as 'b)
end
```

But since I am new in ocaml, I couldn't manage to create an "s" function to have the output I wanted.

What might be a possible way to do that?

Comment: I think @RichouHunter's answer is what you are looking for. Just wanted to point out that there is [print_endline](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALprint_endline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the details of what you're trying to do, but I hope this can help:

```
let s expr =
  let rec loop acc = function
    | `Bs -> "B* "^acc
    | `K -> "K "^acc
    | `App(a,b) -> (loop acc a)^(loop acc b)
  in
  loop "" expr
```

The above works pretty well for the example you gave:

```
s (`App(`App(`App(`Bs, `K), `K), `K));;

- : string = "B* K K K "
```

You'll need to add extra cases to the pattern-match, and maybe a few type annotations if you want helpful type inference instead of the ugly polymorphic variant types.

Answer (score 2):

In case you do not have to stick to :

```
s (`App(`App(`App(`Bs, `K), `K), `K))  ==>  "B* K K K”
```

You could use ppx_deriving to automatically produce a function that transform your type into string (example in utop below) :

```
#require "ppx_deriving.std";;
type t = [`App of (t * t) | `B | `K] [@@deriving show];; (* assuming your type is like this *)
> type t = [ `App of t * t | `B | `K ]
> val pp : Format.formatter -> t -> unit = <fun>
> val show : t -> string = <fun> ...
show (`App (`B , `App (`K , `K)));;
- : string = "`App ((`B, `App ((`K, `K))))"
```